# Identifying file type in Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-type

Linux operating system identifies files by looking at its magic number at the starting of the header. How does windows do it ? Does it also have some kind of magic number mechanism or does it only rely on the file extension ?

Comment: It relies just on the extension. (I'm still not sure whether that's criminally stupid or marvellously brilliant)

Comment: is file extension part of the file header or file system ?

Comment: The file extension is not part of the file's contents. It is derived from metadata, i.e. the name of the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It relies only on the extension, **as provided by the filesystem**; the contents of the file are not examined. See e.g. this article - it talks about Windows XP, but AFAIK the general behavior is shared by all released versions of Windows so far: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859

Comment: so that would mean that the file extension is part of the file system right ?

Comment: was this the reason why older versions of windows and dos only supported three extension letters ?

Comment: @megson: to quote the first sentence, "as provided by the filesystem." So, yes.

Comment: @megson 8.3 limits were nothing to do with that. That was just a design choice for the file systems of the day. Modern file systems still have limits, they are just larger.

Comment: So does linux modify the file header when it receives a file from windows to incorporate the new magic number ?

Comment: @megson: The FAT filesystem only allows 8 letters for filename, and 3 for the extension (long filenames on a FAT volume are a trick perpetrated by the OS). This limit of the filesystem is the reason why most extensions have three letters. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename

Comment: @megson: No, it *reads* the magic numbers - in other words, examines the file to see what known format it resembles. E.g. any GIF file MUST start with the string `GIF`; by looking at a file, I can therefore deduce that if it starts with GIF (and various other heuristics), it's probably a GIF file. The "magic numbers" are this - a collection of characteristic parts of known file formats, not some extra metadata. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files